# Программное создание заранее неизвестного количества массивов

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте.

Такая задача:
Есть файл в нем текст.
Например, в файле 10 символов, я задаю в программе размерность матрицы (char[,]) 2х3.
Учитывая, что 2Х3=6 символов в один массив залезет, мне нужно создать две матрицы 2х3, в одну вместится 6 символов, а в другую - оставшиеся 4 (остальные 2 ячейки пробелами заполню).

Как реализовать это в программе? Нужно обязательно матрица символов (char[,]) или же другой путь, но в итоге прийти к матрице.

Comment: @Northex, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Данный метод возвращает матрицу символов размером X на Y:

```
public static Char[,] GetMatrix(string line,int x, int y)
        {
            Char[,] temp = new char[x,y];
            int it = 0;
            for (int i=0;i<x;i++)
            {
                for (int z=0;z<y;z++)
                {
                    if (it <= line.Length)
                    {
                    temp[i,z] = line[it];
                    } else {
                    temp[i,z] = ' ';
                    }
                    it++;
                }
            }
            return temp;
        }
```

Если входящая строка меньше, чем количество элементов матрицы, то оставшиеся элементы заполняются пробелами.

Comment: Если что - дополню.